# How to create the 8-bit-ish effect near the end of Nero - The Thrill (Porter Robinson Remix)

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects

How can I create the effect at exactly 3:34, 3:39 and 3:42?

Answer (score 1):

A Bitcrusher would be a good bet.

It's a lo-fi distortion effect that allows you to reduce the resolution of digital audio, producing quantization error.

Usually you can control the sample rate, bit depth and sometimes the amount of [dither](http://www.earlevel.com/main/1996/10/20/what-is-dither/).

[Bitcrusher Wikipedia Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcrusher)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a bitcrusher thrown on the master channel (so that it effects everything) with some of the settings on it automated, possibly one of which being the amount of downsampling and/or dry/wet being swept around. Could also have a little bit of distortion/saturation being added also with some automation going on with it's settings.